# In the c language in a multithreaded application how does clock() count time?

Tags: c, multithreading, time

I have not done very much multi threaded development in C, and earlier today I got curious about the library function **clock()**.

How will it behave in a multi threaded application (I will assume using pthread)? Will it count the number of clock ticks since the thread started or since the original program started?

Let us assume I am running a normal two-core CPU like an old honest core 2 duo and two threads are run both trying to count the time using clock().

1. Will both get total number of clock ticks since mother application started or
2. count starting since their own thread started or
3. something third?

Comment: #1. clock() is based on the start time of the process, so any process thread must (should) return identical values, assuming a quality C library.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux and other POSIX-ish systems, `clock` counts total CPU ticks consumed by all threads. Each logical CPU core is counted, so if you have two threads each using an entire core, each second of wall clock will count as about two seconds of CPU time.

On Windows, `clock`, in violation of the standard, does something else.

Answer (score 1):

The C library function `clock()` is supposed to return the number of clock ticks since the process was started.

In reality, the kernel probably (see note) has a "current_ticks_since_boot" variable and remembers when a process was started, and does something like "`current_ticks_since_boot - process->start_time`". It makes no difference how many threads are running (on how many CPUs), or if none of a process' threads are running (e.g. all blocked waiting for something).

*Note: Modern kernels typically use "per CPU" variables to keep track of the current ticks since boot and try to keep the variable for each CPU in sync, and may (do) use a counter built into the CPU that can be exposed to user-space to avoid the cost of a kernel API call.*